# $f: A\to B, X \subset f^{-1}(f(X))$

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have a function

$$f: A\to B$$

I need to prove that, for $X\subset A$

$X\subset f^{-1}(f(X))$

I´ve managed to prove it by doing, for $B\subset Y$:

$$f^{-1}(Y) = \{y\in A\mid f(y) \in Y\}$$

But $f(x)\in f(X)$, so it follows that $x\in f^{-1}(f(X))$, by the arbitrary choice of $x$, we have the result.

Now, I need to prove that "f injective \iff $X=f^{-1}(f(X))$". How can I relate this later proof with this? I cannot see how injectivity will lead in equality.

Comment: What does it mean if for some $X \subset A$ we have $X \subsetneqq f^{-1}(f(X))$?

Comment: Try with $X=\{a\}$ for all $a\in A$ in $X=f^{-1}(f(X))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ injective: Let $x \in f^{-1} (f(X))$. Then by definition, $f(x) \in f(X)$. Therefore, there exists a $x' \in X$ such that $f(x) = f(x')$. But $f$ is injective so $x = x' \in X$.

$X = f^{-1} (f(X))$ $\forall X \subseteq A$. (You didn't add a quantifier in your original post so I'm assuming it has a universal quantifier): Let $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. This implies that $x_2 \in f^{-1} (f(\{x_1\})) = \{x_1\}$. Therefore, $x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: what do you mean by "therefore, there exists a $x'\in X$ such that..."?  Aren't you supposing that?

Comment: how did you get into $X=f^{-1}(f(X))$ in the first paragraph, exactly? Didin't I need to prove that $X$ is included in $f^{-1}(f(X))$ and vice versa?

Comment: We are supposing $x \in f^{-1} f(X)$.

Comment: You've already shown one direction in the subset inclusions. I was showing the other one.

Comment: we're supposing $x$, but what about $x'$?

Comment: It is by definition of $f(X) = \{y \in B \mid \exists x' \in X, y = f(x')\}$