# Show that in $f:A\to B$, and $Z\subset B$, we have: $f(f^{-1}(Z))\subset Z$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm using the following definition of a inverse function:
$$f:A\to B$$
$$f^{-1}(X) = \{x\in A: f(x)\in X\}$$
So, I need to prove that, if $Z\subset B$, we have:

$$f(f^{-1}(Z))\subset Z$$

In other words, for $x\in f(f^{-1}(Z))$, we have to prove that $x\in Z$.
My idea is similar to the later one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680048/f-a-to-b-x-subset-f-1fx).

If  $x\in f(f^{-1}(Z))$, we have that $f(f^{-1}(y)) = x$ for some $y\in Z$. But I'm unable to go from here. Could somebody help me?

Also, how to prove that $f$ is surjective $\iff$ $f(f^{-1})(Z) = Z$?

I'm lost.

Comment: The definition should be $f^{-1}(X) = \{x\in A: f(x)\in X\}$. Probably a typo but I prefer not to edit in case it's the source of the misunderstanding.

Comment: It is perilous to write symbol like " $f(f^{−1}(y))=x$ for some $y \in Z$", do remember that $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, but $f^{-1}$ is a function from $2^B$ to $2^A$. you may want to write like that only when $f$ is injective. As for the proof, if $x \in f(f^{-1}Z))$, we have $u$ in $f^{-1}(Z)$ such that $f(u)=x$. Now by the definition of $f^{-1}(Z)$ you see $x$ is in $Z$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. thanks, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y \in f(f^{-1}(Z))$, then $\exists$ $x \in f^{-1}(Z)$ such that $y = f(x)$. But $x \in f^{-1}(Z)$ just means that $f(x) \in Z$. Hence, $y \in Z$.

> $f$ is surjective $\iff$ $\forall$ $Z \subset B$, $f(f^{-1}(Z)) = Z$.

If $f$ is surjective, then for $y \in Z \subset B$, there exists $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y$, so $f(x) \in Z$, hence $x \in f^{-1}(Z)$, so $f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(Z))$, i.e. $y \in f(f^{-1}(Z))$. So $Z \subset f(f^{-1}(Z))$.

Conversely, let $y \in B$. We have that $\{y\} \subset B$, so $f(f^{-1}(\{y\})) = \{y\}$, and since $f(\varnothing) = \varnothing$, we get that $f^{-1}(\{y\}) \neq \varnothing$. Now $y \in \{y\}$, so $y \in f(f^{-1}(\{y\}))$, hence $\exists x \in f^{-1}(\{y\}) \subset A$, such that $y = f(x)$.